# how to create a non-existing odi target mapping datasource from source datasource?

Tags: etl, oracle-data-integrator

In using odi(oracle data integrator) as you may know there is some mappings which we use to do the transformations between different datasources. In each mapping there must be a source and a target datasource which have been reverse engineered during models creation. Absolutely all the utilized data sources are available at the loaded databases firstly.

But my question is about how to create a target data source structure in the target database based on the source one's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ODI 11g, a temporary interface (yellow interface) allows to drag and drop columns on the target datastore to define its structure. Most of the IKMs have a *Create Target Table* option that can be enabled.

IN ODI 12c, it can't be done unfortunately. If the target datastore has a similar structure as the source, the easiest option is to right-click on the datastore and duplicate it. The copy can be renamed, moved to another model and columns can be edited if needed. Then again the *Create Target Table* option in IKMs can help run the DDL to create it. It is also possible to right click on the model -> *Generate DDL*, to copy it and run it manually.